# When to create new apps in django

Tags: django, django-apps

I've tried reading a few things before asking, but when should new `apps` be created in django?

For instance, I have a website with a domain scanner which will then have registration/login/etc?

Should functionalities like login and registration be (2) separate apps?

What are the best practices in order to determine if a new `app` should be created in django?

Excuse my newbieness, I tried searching and reading [this](http://media.b-list.org/presentations/2008/pycon/reusable_apps.pdf) before asking

but couldn't get a concrete explanation of the best practices for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I do for **login and registration** make an **account** app. It is upto you, how you want to fragment your whole site. Just use intuition.

Comment: Is there "best practices" though ?

Comment: see for any web development framework, you create apps for separate entities. As in lets consider a very basic example, suppose you are making a online shopping site, so you will need separate apps for  **customer, product, order, shipping and so on.** Create apps as totally disjoint from each other in terms of their functionality. This actually grows with experience and your specific needs.

Comment: Is a database table to app a good reference? E.g. a db might have User, Order, Product, etc. Therefore there should be an app for each? I thought that was the whole ethos of django - explicit.

Comment: Yes it could be. It actually makes a lot of sense to do this, but this is not really a hard and fast rule. Most of the people when designing a website from scratch first designs the database, and then from the design chalk out the required apps. I do that too. But I really dont think there is a **best practise**. It totally depends on you.